# SQL Max get the highest id

Tags: sql

I got these query string here...

```
SELECT 
    c.clientid, c.clientname, c.billingdate, 
    i.total - (select ifnull(sum(p.amount), 0) from payment p 
               where p.invoice = i.invoiceid Order by i.invoiceid) AS remaining 
FROM 
    client c 
INNER JOIN 
    invoice i 
WHERE 
    c.clientid = i.client 
ORDER BY 
    clientname
```

What it does, is that it gets a list of all the client, their billing date and their remaining balance. I also have invoices for clients and each of the invoices have a remaining balance. What I am trying to do is grab the clients latest remaining balance (the invoice with the highest id value) per a client.

What the query I have does it list each client multiple times with each remaining balance per an invoice... like so

```
client 1 0.00
client 1 1.00
client 1 3.00
```

What I am looking for is something like is

```
client 1 0.00
client 2 3.00
client 3 5.00
```

I hope it makes sense what I want to do. I have also tried `Order by MAX(i.invoiceid)` but that only returns one client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why the max invoiceid did not work for you

```
SELECT 
    c.clientid, c.clientname, c.billingdate, 
    i.total - (select ifnull(sum(p.amount), 0) from payment p 
               where p.invoice = i.invoiceid Order by i.invoiceid) AS remaining 
FROM 
    client c 
INNER JOIN 
    invoice i 
WHERE 
    c.clientid = i.client 
AND i.invoiceid = (SELECT MAX(i2.invoiceid) FROM invoice i2 WHERE i2.client = i.client) 
ORDER BY 
    clientname
```

Now you should only get the clients latest invoice

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT c.clientid, c.clientname, c.billingdate, i.total - 
(select ifnull(sum(p.amount), 0) from payment p where p.invoice = i.invoiceid Order by i.invoiceid DESC LIMIT 1) AS remaining 
FROM client c inner join invoice i where c.clientid = i.client ORDER BY clientname
```

with the DESCending order and LIMIT 1, you will only select ONE amount per client, the amount with the highest id (and thus the latest)

Comment: I tried your code with the same results. Repeats the client based on how many invoices it has